# How to navigate with state in SvelteKit 2.0?

Tags: sveltekit

In SvelteKit 1.x [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto) had a state option where it was possible to pass state when navigating

```js
goto('/route', {state: {foo: 'bar'}})
```

On the route the value was available via

```
const foo = window.history.state.foo
```

With SvelteKit 2.0 `state` is no longer documented on the `goto` options and there's now [`pushState`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-pushstate), but calling

```
pushState('/route', { foo: 'bar' });
```

will only change the url while staying on the same route.

How to achieve the previous behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just a type bug, see [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/11397).
It is fixed and the docs are updated, but the change is not published to the NPM package as of now (should be in > `2.0.3`).

Comment: I just found this PR https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/11342 - so it looks like state was gone and has been added back in again. A change to 1.0 seems to be though that the value is now available on the new `$page.state` instead of `history.state`